# Does "not" cover the whole sentence?

Tags: conjunctions, coordinating-conjunctions

"Johnny is not tall and fat."

Which of the two does the above sentence mean?

1. Johnny is not tall and not fat.
2. Johnny is not tall, but he is fat.

Comment: Not tall and not fat.

Comment: To me, it could mean "not tall but fat", otherwise, you could say "He is not tall or fat" or "He is neither tall nor fat." This is ambiguous at best.

Comment: If it is important to specify which of the two meanings you want, then do not use "Johnny is not tall and fat."

Comment: If he's not tall and not fat, say "Johnny is neither tall nor fat."  If he's not tall, but he is fat, say "Johnny is fat, but not tall."

Comment: This is a problem about writing, not English. In real (spoken) language, intonation and rhythm would make the intended meaning clear, but written English doesn't record those. ***All*** written sentences are multiply ambiguous, and we don't even notice the ambiguities because of our contextual presuppositions. But computers do notice them, as 50 years of automatic translation research has demonstrated.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Some sentences suffer from what is called ***syntactic ambiguity*** (see [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Syntactic_ambiguity)). This means (roughly) that it is not clear which words go with which other words.

The sentence "Johnny is not tall and fat" is syntactically ambiguous. It can mean either

1. Johnny is not tall and not fat.
2. Johnny is not tall, but he is fat.

(There is even a third possible meaning; see @Brian Donovan's comment, below.)

Most English speakers, however, would probably not even notice the ambiguity since such a sentence is *almost always* used to mean (1).

Comment: Logically it might even best be parsed as "Johnny is NOT (tall AND fat)." In other words, the propositions that Johnny is tall and that Johnny is fat are not *both* true: either or neither may be true, but not both. This bizarre meaning is yet one more reason to redesign the sentence if normal human communication is the aim.

Comment: "He is not tall and fat, just tall", so it could be interpreted as the exact opposite of what it could mean. Of course, if the sentence is spoken, the way you stress one word or another would let you know more specifically what it's supposed to mean. But when written, it's anyone's guess.

Comment: @MorganFR, that is true and *essentially* Brian Donovan's point in the comment above. I edited my answer to point interested readers to these comments.

Comment: Yes, it is part of his point, I was just providing an example to make it clearer.